# Pass logged in username from phpbb3 to phpfreechat

Tags: php, phpbb3

Hey I've built a membership site around the phpbb3 login system. You can't access some parts of the site unless you're logged in, including the chat room.

I want phpfreechat to autologin with the username that is logged into phpbb3.

Here is how far I've gotten.

at the top of the chat room page ...

```
<?php 

session_start();
include '../phpbb3/phpbb3class.php'; 

if(!$user->data['is_registered']) { header('Location: ../login/'); }
$_SESSION['chatname'] = $user->data['username'];

?>
```

if I echo $_SESSION['chatname'] I get the correct value.

now in the config.php file of phpfreechat, I try to use the login hook provided...

```
$GLOBALS['pfc_hooks']['pfc.before.auth'][5] = function ($app, $req, $res,) {
   return function () use ($app, $req, $res,) 
      {

    return ($_SESSION['chatname']);

   };
};
```

at the top of the config.php file I also session_start();

This doesn't work, I load the chat page up and the chat template is blank with no logged in user :(

Can anybody help?

Comment: I do not think somebody will give you a straight answer because your question is complicated... and I would rather program something from scratch than trying to have one single session.. just my opinion

Comment: someone who is familiar with phpfreechat should be able to answer this. If you're not familiar with phpfreechat then yeah this might look a bit alien.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look to this code: https://github.com/kerphi/phpfreechat/tree/master/server/contrib/phpbb3-auth

It shows how to integrate phpbb3 login to the chat using phpfreechat's pfc.before.auth hook.

You can adapte auth.php script to match your phpbb3 installation.